# How to Re-instate Android Foreground Service UI?

Tags: android, foreground-service

If a user terminates the UI of an Android foreground service, when the service needs to use the UI to present its information and the application attempts to display the popup an *Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException* 'Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@260c22b is not valid" is encountered and terminates the service.

Currently, when the service UI is present, in the foreground or background, the popup is displayed and if accepted the UI component of the service is presented. If the UI component has been terminated, I would like the UI component to be re-established and the behavior to be the same.